# Not able to add user in Bulk in Google Group app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to add run below script but users are not getting added

```
function doAddGoogleGroupMember(){

  var user = "i.s.e@example.com, a.s.e@example.com";
  var groupEmail = "g-s@example.com";

  var member = {
    email: user,
    role: "MEMBER"
  };
  try {
    member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
    Logger.log('User %s added as a %s of group %s.', user, role, groupEmail);
  }
  catch(e) {
    if (e.message == "Member already exists.") {
      Logger.log('User %s is already in the group %s.', user, groupEmail);
    }
  }
}
```

But When I mentioned single user like in below script, user get added to the group

```
function doAddGoogleGroupMember(){
    var user = "i.s.e@example.com";
    var groupEmail = "g-s@example.com";
    var member = {
      email: user,
      role: "MEMBER"
      };
    try {
    member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
    Logger.log('User %s added as a %s of group %s.', user, role, groupEmail);
    }
    catch(e) {
    if (e.message == "Member already exists.") {
      Logger.log('User %s is already in the group %s.', user, groupEmail);
    }
    }
}
```

Please guide me how to work 1st script as I want to know how to add more than one user through App-script in Google group

Comment: Why not log all errors, and if it isn't one you planned for (like an existing member), *throw* the error again so you can know it exists and handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this first,

```
 var member = [{
      email: user1,
      role: "MEMBER"
      },
      {
      email: user2,
      role: "MEMBER"
      }
    ];
```

This should solve your problem. 
If not, your way out can be like the following,

```
function doAddGoogleGroupMember(user,groupEmail){
    var member = {
      email: user,
      role: "MEMBER"
      };
    try {
    member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
    Logger.log('User %s added as a %s of group %s.', user, role, groupEmail);
    }
    catch(e) {
    if (e.message == "Member already exists.") {
      Logger.log('User %s is already in the group %s.', user, groupEmail);
    }
    }
}

function startHere()
{
  var mappingArray = {'i.s.e@example.com':'g-s@example.com','a.s.e@example.com':'g-s@example.com'};
  for (var key in mappingArray ) {
    doAddGoogleGroupMember(key,mappingArray[key]);
  }
}
```

Here you should call `startHere` to run the whole function. Provide your user email and group email as key/value pair in `mappingArray` . Iterate through a loop and call the `doAddGoogleGroupMember` function.

Comment: thank you for the information @DarpanSanghavi actually I mention only two emails here. However, there will be a bulk email address will be present and I will be giving path through google sheet cell. and in the cell, the email address will be separated using a comma.

Is there any solution where all email address present sheet cell separated using comma can get added to the group and no need to write code explicitly for each email address

Comment: Above code should work with Google Sheet data also. Try parsing Google sheet data and create `mappingArray` from it. Rest of the things stay as it is.